How can I slow down drag behavior with D3/JavaScript?
I am designing a visualization which begins with the user drawing points on the screen as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/jtr13/j2yrknf3/25/
The relevant part of the code (inspired by this answer) is:
svg.on("mousedown", mousedown)
  .on("mouseup", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
  const new_x = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const new_y = yScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[1]);
  svg.append("circle")
    .data([{x: new_x, y: new_y}])
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", "3");

svg.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
  const new_x = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const new_y = yScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[1]);
  svg.append("circle")
    .data([{x: new_x, y: new_y}])
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", "3"); 
}

function mouseup() {
  svg.on("mousemove", null);
}

The problem is that too many points are added during mousemove. I would like points to be added at about 1/5 or 1/10 of the current rate. I tried adding delays of various sorts and nothing worked. How can I slow down the drag behavior?

Throttle Function: Limits how often a function runs by making it wait a set time between calls.
Throttled Mousemove: Slows down how often the mousemove event runs, so it only triggers every 100 milliseconds. You can change the timing if you want it faster or slower.


// Throttle function to limit the rate at which the mousemove function is called
function throttle(func, delay) {
  let lastCall = 0;
  return function(...args) {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - lastCall >= delay) {
      lastCall = now;
      return func(...args);
    }
  };
}

// Width and height
const w = 400;
const h = 350;

// Create scale functions
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 4])
  .range([0, w]);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 4])
  .range([h, 0]);

// Define the SVG container
const svg = d3.select("div#plot")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("fill", "lightblue");

// Add event listeners for mouse interactions
svg.on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);

// Function for mousedown event
function mousedown() {
  const new_x = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const new_y = yScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[1]);
  svg.append("circle")
    .data([{ x: new_x, y: new_y }])
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", "3");
  d3.select("h3#num").text("Number of points: " + d3.selectAll("circle").size());

  svg.on("mousemove", throttledMousemove);
}

// Function for mousemove event with throttling
const throttledMousemove = throttle(function () {
  const new_x = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
  const new_y = yScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[1]);
  svg.append("circle")
    .data([{ x: new_x, y: new_y }])
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
    .attr("r", "3");
  d3.select("h3#num").text("Number of points: " + d3.selectAll("circle").size());
}, 100); // Adjust the delay to control the rate (e.g., 100 milliseconds)

// Function for mouseup event
function mouseup() {
  svg.on("mousemove", null);
}

// Function to restart and clear all points
function restart() {
  d3.selectAll("circle").remove();
  d3.select("h3#num").text("Number of points: 0");
}
<h3 id="info">Click and drag to add points.</h3>
<h3 id="num">Number of points: 0</h3>
<button onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
<p></p>
<div id="plot"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>




This works perfectly. Thank you!
